# Ubuntu keyboard and mouse locked on the login screen

Tags: keyboard, mouse

after booting into Linux Ubuntu today, my keyboard and mouse were locked.
I've tried to connect external mouse and keyboard to my laptop, but they didn't work either. I have tried different key combinations like superkey + L, ctrl + alt + L.
After that I tried going into BIOS and tried booting into different versions of Ubuntu.
I also tried booting into safemode (I don't remember what it was actually called) and it let me use the console, where I tried things like `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`, I get several lines from `sudo apt-get update` that tell me that they cannot retrieve this and that from x domain and used old domain instead. Then I also tried `sudo apt-get xserver-xorg-input-all` (Or something similar to this command, I found it on a forum), and it also told me that it couldn't retrieve something, and suggested that maybe I should try `--fix-missing` or `sudo apt-get update`.

So far nothing helped, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: You've provided on specifics as to what Ubuntu product & release you're asking about.  You also mention trying different versions?  (or do you mean different kernel versions offered by the grub boot menu? as they'll all be for the same *unstated* Ubuntu release), as well as not providing the actual error message(s) you received; thus we're limited with how we can help you.  I suggest reading the messages & acting on them, or providing them for us, so we can help you to act on them.

Comment: What I meant by different versions was the kernel versions through the grub boot. 
The error message after xserver-xorg-input-all are as follows:
"Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/xserver-xorg-input-libinput_0.29.0-1_amd64.deb Temporary failure resolving 'no.archive.ubuntu.com'"
"Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg/xserver-xorg-input-all_7.7+19ubuntu14_amd64.deb Temporary failure resolving 'no.archive.ubuntu.com'"

Comment: And another one:

"Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xf86-input-wacom/xserver-xorg-input-wacom_0.39.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb Temporary failure resolving 'no.archive.ubuntu,com'"

Comment: However I am not sure if that command will even help my case.

Comment: Sudo apt-get update will give me A LOT of errors, and instead of typing them one by one by hand, here's a photo of all of them https://imgur.com/a/GqEiYP4

Comment: Did you enable networking before entering recovery mode? There's an item in the grub menu for this. Your machine has quite probably ended up in this state becuase you uninstalled a package that `xserver-xorg-input-all` depended on. If you want to investigate, search for `xserver` in `/var/log/apt/history.log` (or one of the rotated logs) to find when it was uninstalled and why.

Comment: Omg, thank you, it's stupid of me not to enable networking, but yes, I didn't enable networking and that's why it couldn't fetch the files from the websites. After enabling networking xserver-xorg-input-all did it, THANK YOU SO MUCH frippe!